# Unable to use dart:math random

Tags: dart

```
import 'dart:math' show Random;



dice() {

    int D1 = Random.nextInt(6);
    print("the dice value is $D1")
 }
```

Hey guys so I have this dice function and I can't get away of generating a random integer between 1- 6

any suggestions?

here is a link to the github repo

https://github.com/Allanbikundo/Comand-Line-Monopoly

pulls are accepted :)

Comment: nextInt is from [0, 6). Use `nextInt(6) + 1`.

Comment: Well i dont think it will work because my ide isnt even recognizing the function nextInt

Comment: should be `new Random()`. It's a class

Comment: thanks @Li357 it works